# Is there an easy way to refactor one file(more than 1000 line) regarding a special pattern?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, refactoring

is there an easy way to refactor one file(more than 1000 line) regarding a special pattern ?

For Example I have a lot of code, the problem is all the property names are with small capital letters ,but in c# we need big capital letters.

How to do this in an easy way, remember the properties are used throughout the entire project(visual studio 2013) ?

Comment: Check out [Find and Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/139eef4h.aspx).

Comment: Use ReSharper for example.

Comment: There´s no simple algorithm by which you can do this. Just *searching* for properties isn´t trivial as it assumes your code to be formatted in a special manner (for instance only auto-properties, or knowledge of your bracing). So this question is obviously far too braod as long as you don´t provide how your code looks like currently that you want to replace. Even then this question isn´t well suited here as questions about tools and libraries are off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Refactoring in general is not an easy task and involves a whole bunch of techniques. But if it comes down to renaming properties and fixing naming issues then [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) from JetBrains has been a great help.

Resharper lets you fix naming issues (like wrong capitalization) not only for the single occurrance but on project and solution level, too.

[image]